# How to export as .csv without changing column names' dashes and spaces into dots?

Tags: r

In my dataframe I have column names with dashes and spaces e.g. address-type. When I try to export as .csv, the dashes and spaces change into dots, so "address-type" changes into address.type in the .csv file.

When importing .csvs I used check.names = FALSE, however, there doesn't seem to be a similar function when exporting.

Any help on this annoying problem would be greatly appriciated!

Edits to the question with example code:

```
df1 = data.frame("x 1" = 1, "x-2" = 2, check.names = F)
df2 = data.frame("y 1" = 1, "y-2" = 2, check.names = F)

Dflist <- list(df1, df2)
write.csv(Dflist[1],file="test.csv")
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. If I define `df = data.frame("x 1" = 1, "x-2" = 2, check.names = F)` and then do `write.csv(df, file = "test.csv")`, the first row of the file is `"","x 1","x-2"`, which looks just fine.

Comment: Hmm that is really wierd. I tried your code, and as you mentioned the dashes and gaps are intact. I'll have to investigate further to see, whether the problem is caused due to something else. Nonetheless, thanks for the prompt reply!

Comment: Hi Gregor, I was able to reproduce the problem. I've edited the question now with example code. Would be great if you could look at it.

Comment: `Dflist[1]` in the last line should be `Dflist[[1]]`.  `Dflist[1]` is not a data frame, it is a one component list containing a data.frame, but `Dflist[[1]]` is a data frame.

Comment: See R-FAQ [The difference between [ and [[ in list indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1169456/903061), also https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/643381054758363136?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

Use write_csv  insterad of write.csv from the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) ecosystem, which is part of the [readr](https://readr.tidyverse.org/) library.

It does exactly what you want.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem for me.